# load xml string into an easy to use object in vb.net web application

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have seen and did some simple xml tasks with php using SimpleXML and it lives up to its name.

I want to know if there is a way to load the xml document into object similar to how SimpleXML function does but for vb.net.

The tutorial I have for vb.net uses System.Xml and has nodelist and nodes as different variable types, making xml data retrieval look like a nightmare.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I will need to be able to parse through multiple different formats of xml some of which I haven't seen yet. Part of my current xml is below:

```
<AuditData>
    <ProcessTime>2128</ProcessTime>
    <Timestamp>2014-05-06 11:35:52.042</Timestamp>
    <RequestHost>127.0.0.1</RequestHost>
    <ServerName>SIS</ServerName>
    <ServerId>01</ServerId>
    <SchemaRelease>2005/06</SchemaRelease>
    <HydraCoreRelease>2.0.201405051526</HydraCoreRelease>
    <HydraEnumerationsRelease>1.0.201405051526</HydraEnumerationsRelease>
    <MerlinRelease>N/A</MerlinRelease>
</AuditData>
<PaginationData currentPage="1" totalPages="10"/>
<ServiceHotel xsi:type="ServiceHotel" availToken="1T30xpRg+eHNFvzJSa38uwbd">
    <DirectPayment>Y</DirectPayment>
    <ContractList>
        <Contract>
            <Name>NRF-TODOS1~</Name>
            <IncomingOffice code="1"/>
            <Classification code="NRF">Non refundable rate</Classification>
        </Contract>
    </ContractList>
    <DateFrom date="20140706"/>
    <DateTo date="20140708"/>
    <Currency code="EUR">Euro</Currency>
    <PackageRate>N</PackageRate>
    <TravelAgent>N</TravelAgent>
    <HotelInfo xsi:type="ProductHotel">
        <Code>1499</Code>
        <Name>Amic Gala</Name>
        <ImageList>
            <Image>
                <Type>jpg</Type>
                <Order>1</Order>
                <VisualizationOrder>1</VisualizationOrder>
                <Url>http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/00/001499/001499a_hb_w_002.jpg</Url>
            </Image>
            <Image>
                <Type>jpg</Type>
                <Order>2</Order>
                <VisualizationOrder>2</VisualizationOrder>
                <Url>http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/00/001499/001499a_hb_r_005.jpg</Url>
            </Image>
        </ImageList>
        <Category type="SIMPLE" code="3EST" shortname="3*">3 STARS</Category>
        <Destination type="SIMPLE" code="PMI">
            <Name>Majorca</Name>
            <ZoneList>
                <Zone type="SIMPLE" code="74">Ca'n Pastilla</Zone>
            </ZoneList>
        </Destination>
        <ChildAge ageFrom="0" ageTo="12"/>
        <Position latitude="39.53611999999999682132" longitude="2.71932000000000018147"/>
    </HotelInfo>
    <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
            <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
            <Occupancy>
                <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
                <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
            </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom SHRUI="azRX8L17pO1vJQ18i8A7+w==" availCount="10" onRequest="N">
            <Board type="SIMPLE" code="RO-E10" shortname="RO">ROOM ONLY</Board>
            <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBT-E10" characteristic="ST">Double or Twin STANDARD</RoomType>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <FreeNights>0</FreeNights>
            <Price>
                <Amount>94.560</Amount>
                <SellingPrice mandatory="Y">94.560</SellingPrice>
                <NetPrice>78.960</NetPrice>
                <Commission>16.500</Commission>
            </Price>
            <CancellationPolicies>
                <CancellationPolicy amount="94.560" dateFrom="20140505" time="2359"/>
            </CancellationPolicies>
        </HotelRoom>
    </AvailableRoom>
    <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
            <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
            <Occupancy>
                <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
                <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
            </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom SHRUI="82LafAHrfGSTNGqn9I45+g==" availCount="10" onRequest="N">
            <Board type="SIMPLE" code="BB-E10" shortname="BB">BED AND BREAKFAST</Board>
            <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBT-E10" characteristic="ST">Double or Twin STANDARD</RoomType>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <FreeNights>0</FreeNights>
            <Price>
                <Amount>98.560</Amount>
                <SellingPrice mandatory="Y">98.560</SellingPrice>
                <NetPrice>82.300</NetPrice>
                <Commission>16.500</Commission>
            </Price>
            <CancellationPolicies>
                <CancellationPolicy amount="98.560" dateFrom="20140505" time="2359"/>
            </CancellationPolicies>
        </HotelRoom>
    </AvailableRoom>
</ServiceHotel>
```

After I have extracted the necessary info I will need to display many hotels with each of its rooms available.

I just have an issue with getting the data in a manageable way.

Answer (score 1):

For reference always start with the documentation
[XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Using the XML posted I created a literal to use as a demo:

```
    Dim xe As XElement = <root xmlns:xsi="http://example.com/ns1">
                             <AuditData>
                                 <ProcessTime>2128</ProcessTime>
                                 <Timestamp>2014-05-06 11:35:52.042</Timestamp>
                                 <RequestHost>127.0.0.1</RequestHost>
                                 <ServerName>SIS</ServerName>
                                 <ServerId>01</ServerId>
                                 <SchemaRelease>2005/06</SchemaRelease>
                                 <HydraCoreRelease>2.0.201405051526</HydraCoreRelease>
                                 <HydraEnumerationsRelease>1.0.201405051526</HydraEnumerationsRelease>
                                 <MerlinRelease>N/A</MerlinRelease>
                             </AuditData>
                             <PaginationData currentPage="1" totalPages="10"/>
                             <ServiceHotel xsi:type="ServiceHotel" availToken="1T30xpRg+eHNFvzJSa38uwbd">
                                 <DirectPayment>Y</DirectPayment>
                                 <ContractList>
                                     <Contract>
                                         <Name>NRF-TODOS1~</Name>
                                         <IncomingOffice code="1"/>
                                         <Classification code="NRF">Non refundable rate</Classification>
                                     </Contract>
                                 </ContractList>
                                 <DateFrom date="20140706"/>
                                 <DateTo date="20140708"/>
                                 <Currency code="EUR">Euro</Currency>
                                 <PackageRate>N</PackageRate>
                                 <TravelAgent>N</TravelAgent>
                                 <HotelInfo xsi:type="ProductHotel">
                                     <Code>1499</Code>
                                     <Name>Amic Gala</Name>
                                     <ImageList>
                                         <Image>
                                             <Type>jpg</Type>
                                             <Order>1</Order>
                                             <VisualizationOrder>1</VisualizationOrder>
                                             <Url>http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/00/001499/001499a_hb_w_002.jpg</Url>
                                         </Image>
                                         <Image>
                                             <Type>jpg</Type>
                                             <Order>2</Order>
                                             <VisualizationOrder>2</VisualizationOrder>
                                             <Url>http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/00/001499/001499a_hb_r_005.jpg</Url>
                                         </Image>
                                     </ImageList>
                                     <Category type="SIMPLE" code="3EST" shortname="3*">3 STARS</Category>
                                     <Destination type="SIMPLE" code="PMI">
                                         <Name>Majorca</Name>
                                         <ZoneList>
                                             <Zone type="SIMPLE" code="74">Ca'n Pastilla</Zone>
                                         </ZoneList>
                                     </Destination>
                                     <ChildAge ageFrom="0" ageTo="12"/>
                                     <Position latitude="39.53611999999999682132" longitude="2.71932000000000018147"/>
                                 </HotelInfo>
                                 <AvailableRoom>
                                     <HotelOccupancy>
                                         <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
                                         <Occupancy>
                                             <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
                                             <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
                                         </Occupancy>
                                     </HotelOccupancy>
                                     <HotelRoom SHRUI="azRX8L17pO1vJQ18i8A7+w==" availCount="10" onRequest="N">
                                         <Board type="SIMPLE" code="RO-E10" shortname="RO">ROOM ONLY</Board>
                                         <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBT-E10" characteristic="ST">Double or Twin STANDARD</RoomType>
                                         <ProductType>P</ProductType>
                                         <FreeNights>0</FreeNights>
                                         <Price>
                                             <Amount>94.560</Amount>
                                             <SellingPrice mandatory="Y">94.560</SellingPrice>
                                             <NetPrice>78.960</NetPrice>
                                             <Commission>16.500</Commission>
                                         </Price>
                                         <CancellationPolicies>
                                             <CancellationPolicy amount="94.560" dateFrom="20140505" time="2359"/>
                                         </CancellationPolicies>
                                     </HotelRoom>
                                 </AvailableRoom>
                                 <AvailableRoom>
                                     <HotelOccupancy>
                                         <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
                                         <Occupancy>
                                             <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
                                             <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
                                         </Occupancy>
                                     </HotelOccupancy>
                                     <HotelRoom SHRUI="82LafAHrfGSTNGqn9I45+g==" availCount="10" onRequest="N">
                                         <Board type="SIMPLE" code="BB-E10" shortname="BB">BED AND BREAKFAST</Board>
                                         <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBT-E10" characteristic="ST">Double or Twin STANDARD</RoomType>
                                         <ProductType>P</ProductType>
                                         <FreeNights>0</FreeNights>
                                         <Price>
                                             <Amount>98.560</Amount>
                                             <SellingPrice mandatory="Y">98.560</SellingPrice>
                                             <NetPrice>82.300</NetPrice>
                                             <Commission>16.500</Commission>
                                         </Price>
                                         <CancellationPolicies>
                                             <CancellationPolicy amount="98.560" dateFrom="20140505" time="2359"/>
                                         </CancellationPolicies>
                                     </HotelRoom>
                                 </AvailableRoom>
                             </ServiceHotel></root>
```

To get the server name the code would be

```
    Dim s As String = xe.<AuditData>.<ServerName>.Value
```

Comment: Why not edit existing answer? Either way, got a video using xelement and will use the reference to assist in filling in the gaps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given information about what the XML looks like, what you want to do with it, etc.  The easiest is to use the XElement class if your manipulations are simple.

Given a path to the xml file loading it is

```
    Dim xe As XElement = XElement.Load(PathToXMLfile)
```

To save the file

```
    xe.Save(PathToXMLfile)
```

Comment: I have added an xml sample. I don't need to make changes to the xml, just display the data I get from another source/api.

Comment: If XElement is the way to go, can you link a tutorial on how to use it?